# Various Stutterings on Samsung Galaxy Nexus

Tags: samsung-galaxy-nexus

So I've had my Samsung Galaxy Nexus for a while now, round about a year, and it has this odd set of problems where some of the core functions of the OS stutter. What do I mean by this? The most egregious and obvious example is while typing, occasionally my keyboard will find it pertinent to, without prompting, close about 95% of the way, stall, then open and close in quick succession many times in an unpredictable fashion. This makes typing very difficult as when I go to type, the phone will sometimes make it impossible to access the keyboard. While it does this odd stutter, the normal "back" button shows the "close keyboard" icon. When tapped, the keyboard will continue its stuttering until it realizes I wanted it to close, when it closes. I've tried reinstalling the keyboard, resetting the phone to factory settings, and different keyboards like swiftkey.

Along with this keyboard malfunction is the unfortunate glitch in the phone itself, where if it feels like it, the phone will mute and unmute so fast that neither me nor the person on the other end can make out what the other is saying.

More recently some of the system sounds, such as notifications, have begun stuttering. In what sounds like a failure to buffer the sounds before playing them, it sounds like a skipping record player.

The reason I'm saying all of these in the same post is that I suspect my OS is to blame. One remedy that may or may not work (extensive testing not yet completed) is to make sure there are no finger smudges on the screen. My screen is in tact but has a very small scratch about half an inch long in the middle. I'd appreciate if anyone could point me in the right direction; either to reinstalling my OS from scratch or towards a new phone.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Most of your symptoms sound like the touchscreen thinking you are tapping it when you're not; if that's it, no software change will help. A drawing/painting app will show you if the screen is "touching itself", as it were.

Comment: Hello Dan, in the past few days I decided to give that a shot to diagnose the problem, but no go. Every time it exhibits the symptoms I would bring up the paint app, but nothing happened. I tried to touch the screen as little as possible while changing apps, and even simulated typing to try and trigger it.